# Is there any formula to find number of Pythagorean triplets between two integers 2 and j, j>2?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Given $j \geq 5$, is there a formula for the number of Pythagorean triplets $(a, b, c)$ satisfying the constraint that $a, b, c \leq j$?

There exists at least one Pythagorean triplet for $j\geq5$; the question is how to find the exact number of Pythagorean triplets for large $j$.

Comment: What does it mean for a triplet to be between two integers? Do you want the hypotenuse to be between the two integers? There is a tabulation at http://oeis.org/A224921

Comment: for example, between 2 and 6, there is one Pythagorean triplet, namely, 3, 4, and 5. Also between 2 and 6, there is only one triplet. However, between 2 and 11, there are two triplets: (3,4,5), (6,8,10).

Comment: Voted to close pending an actual answer to Gerry's question.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Regardless of whether the question is appropriate for MO, I think that the OP's reply to Gerry makes it clear what is meant by the question

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed, it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @YemonChoi:  If the reply to Gerry's question was clear, then (without looking at the edited version of the question) how many Pythagorean triplets are there between 7 and 11?  Is $(6,8,10)$ between 7 and 11?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg In my interpretation, no. One wants all elements of the triple to lie strictly between the two limits

Comment: These are the partial sums of [OEIS sequence A046080](https://oeis.org/A046080); there is a formula there for $A046080(n)$ in terms of the prime factors of $n$.  A "closed-form" formula for $A224921(n)$ would seem unlikely.

Answer (score 8):

The question here was studied (in a slightly more generalized version) by Sierpinski (1906) in Polish; asymptotics were found by Fricker (1977, 1982) and Fischer (1979) both in German; and an unconditional *upper* bound was established by Stronina (1969) in Russian.

As for English, you can find these references (and others) in, for example, the paper:

> Nowak, W. G., & Recknagel, W. (1989). The distribution of Pythagorean triples and a three-dimensional divisor problem. *Math. J. Okayama Univ, 31*, 213-220. [**Link**](http://www.math.okayama-u.ac.jp/mjou/mjou1-46/mjou_pdf/mjou_31/mjou_31_213.pdf) (no paywall).

Here is an excerpt from the first page:

[image]

The reference here comes from backtracking; first:

> Benito, M., & Varona, J. L. (2002). Pythagorean triangles with legs less than n. *Journal of computational and applied mathematics, 143*(1), 117-126. [**Link**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042701004964) (no paywall).

In there, the authors point to an earlier paper (p. 118):

> Kühleitner, M. (1993, December). An omega theorem on Pythagorean triples. In *Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg* (Vol. 63, No. 1, pp. 105-113). Springer Berlin/Heidelberg. [**Link**](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02941336?LI=true).

The last paper is, unfortunately, only visible as a preview; but it is written in English (despite the German title) and contains a reference to the Nowak and Recknagel paper excerpted above.

Comment: I counted 1216894 triples below 637460, of which 101461 are prime. The latter number seems consistent with $\frac{1}{2\pi}N$ rather than with $\frac{4}{\pi}N$. The number 1216894 for all triples in turn seems consistent with $\frac{1}{2\pi}N \log{N}$ rather than $\frac{4}{\pi} N\log{N}$. The factor of $8$ discrepancy clearly comes from  one paper counting integer triples and the other POSITIVE integer triples.

Comment: to be precise: $n$ is positive in the paper above, while $r$ and $s$ can be negative and can be switched with each other.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch (Perhaps I am missing something obvious but...) shouldn't allowing $r$ and $s$ to be negative create a factor $4$ discrepancy? There is an $n \geq 1$ requirement...

Comment: yes, but as I mentioned in the previous comment, another factor of 2 must come from switching $r$ and $s$. My counting of positive triples assumed $0< r < s < n$.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Ah, yes... something obvious! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is equivalent to asking for all Pythagorean triples with bounds on the hypotenuse and *a variant* of that problem is treated in the article [ENUMERATION OF ALL PRIMITIVE PYTHAGOREAN TRIPLES WITH HYPOTENUSE LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO N](http://vixra.org/pdf/1310.0211v1.pdf)

A simple estimate for the number of primitive Pythagorean triples is due to Lehmer: it is less than $N/2\pi$

Turning to the original problem of enumerating all triples, the following observation helps:

$a^2+b^2=c^2 \implies a=2uv, b=v^2-u^2, c=u^2+v^2; u\le v$
which leads to the problem of finding $\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^{n}r(i)$, where $r(i)$ is the number of ways to write $i$ as the sum of two squares of signed integers (cf e.g. [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) ).

The answer is then the aforementioned sum $\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^{n}r(i)$

Comment: is there a simple asymptotic for the latter number?

Comment: on the wolfram page the asymptotic formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n}r(i) = \pi n + O(\sqrt{n})$ is given

Comment: Yes, the equivalence to "all Pythagorean triples with bounds on the hypotenuse" makes it straightforward to search for (I posted a few example references after using such a query) ... But I'm [somewhat] wary about the reference you provide as it exists only on **vixra** ...

Comment: Your parametrization of Pythagorean triples is inaccurate in the details: it requires $u$ and $v$ to be relatively prime and of opposite parity, and then the formula parametrizes all primitive Pythagorean triples, not all Pythagorean triples. In other words, as stated, your method double-counts some triples and omits other triples.

Comment: Also, the seeming uniform distribution of primitive triples would seem, euristically, to imply an asymptotic of $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_1^N \lfloor \frac{N}{x}\rfloor dx \simeq \frac{1}{2 \pi} N\log(N)$ for all triples. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but I recently solved a programming problem regarding this question, the article was shared above but the method was not explicitly shared here.

Following this article: [Pythagorean triangles with legs less than n](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042701004964#aep-abstract-id6) there is quite a nice solution

We know that each primitive Pythagorean triple can be represented by
\begin{align*}
    a &= x^2 - y^2 \\
    b &= 2xy \\
    c &= x^2 + y^2
\end{align*}
Following the paper lets define a few sets.
\begin{align*}
    R(n) &= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq n, 0 < x < y\}\\
    P(n) &= \{(x, y) \in R(n) \mid \gcd(x, y) = 1, x + y \equiv 1 \pmod{2}\} \\
    Q(n) &= \{(x, y) \in R(n) \mid \gcd(x, y) = 1\}
\end{align*}
Note that $|P(n)|$ is exactly the amount of Pythagorean triples with hypotenuse less than or equal to $n$, which is what we are trying to find. Now according to the paper **Lemma 3** states
\begin{equation*}
    |P(n)| = \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k|Q(\frac{n}{2^k})|
\end{equation*}
Note that we changed the region but the proof is the same.

Now all that is left is to calculate $Q(n)$. I define a few equations which are identical to the article, but easier to read.
\begin{align*}
    L(t) &= |\{(x, y) \in R(t^2)\}| = |R(t^2)| \\
    L'(t) &= |\{(x, y) \in R(t^2) \mid \gcd(x, y) = 1\}| = |Q(t^2)|
\end{align*}
Following the exact same proof as the article we have
\begin{align*}
    L(t) &= \sum_{1 \leq d \leq t} L'(\frac{t}{d}) \\
    L'(t) &= \sum_{1 \leq d \leq t} \mu(d) L(\frac{t}{d})
\end{align*}
Therefore we have,
\begin{align*}
    |Q(n)| &= L'(\sqrt{n}) \\
    &= \sum_{1 \leq d \leq \sqrt{n}} \mu(d) L(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{d}) \\
    &= \sum_{1 \leq d \leq \sqrt{n}} \mu(d) |R(\frac{n}{d^2})|
\end{align*}

Now, using brute force a computer can easily find all the lattice points in $R(n)$, and with a good Möbius sieve we can get a nice easy solution.

I have a python package where I add functions like these if anyone is interested to see the code.

1. [Mobius Sieve](https://mathslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mathslib.html#mathslib.numtheory.mobius_k_sieve)
2. [Number of primitve Pythagorean triples with hypotenuse less than n](https://mathslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mathslib.html#mathslib.numtheory.count_primitive_pythagorean_triples)